# Installation related questions

Tags: installation, installshield

I am very new to creating installer packages for the company softwares. We are using InstallShield as building block.
I have below basic doubts:
1) What is the need to write the application data to registry?
2) When we release newer version of software, generally should we delete the older versions automatically and install new one?
3) What are the different things to take care in the lifecycle of instalaltions?

Answer (score 0):

1. The applications data are entered into registry by the installer itself, it will be used for any future references. It has the version, GUID etc, which will be used during upgrades, uninstalling etc.
2. Its not necessary to delete the older files unless required. You can however set the options to uninstall previous version for upgrades.
3. You need to check the versions, GUIDs, upgrade information, if any hard-coded values etc.